# Refresh Javascript variable on inputfield change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to change the value of variable dynamically WHEN an inputfield (text type) value changes.

the inputfield value is dynamic as well.

so, basically, when the inputfield value changes, the variable value should change accordingly.

**this is my current code:**

```
$('#map-txt').change(function(e){
var myData = document.getElementById("myText").value;

var myVar = eval("[" + myData + "]");
});
```

So, the value of the `myText` is an AJAX result which will be updated every X seconds. *works fine.*

the value of `myVar` is the same as the `myText`  value but this only works when I load the page and/or refresh the page?

I'm not entirely sure if it doesn't work because I am mixing jquery with pure javascript or what I am doing is totally wrong.

what i need to do is to change the value of the `myVar` without page refresh.

any help would be appreciated.

EDIT, THIS IS MY AJAX code:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {

    function load() {
        $.ajax({ //create an ajax request to load_page.php
            type: "GET",
            url: "SOMEPAGE.php",
            dataType: "html", //expect html to be returned                
            success: function (response) {
                $("#map-directions").html(response);

                var input = document.getElementById("map-directions").innerHTML;
                document.getElementById("map-txt").value = document.getElementById("map-directions").innerHTML;




                setTimeout(load, 800);



            }

        });
    }

    load();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Add a `$('#map-txt').trigger('change')` whenever you updated its value via AJAX. The `change` doesn't get triggered when there is no user interaction with it.

Comment: you are using $.ajax($.post or $.get )???

Answer (score 0):

`$('#map-txt').change( ... );` only gets triggered on user interaction, not when you update the field via AJAX or anything else.
Just add a `$('#map-txt').trigger('change');` to the functionality that does the update via AJAX.

```
success: function (response) {
    $("#map-directions").html(response);
    var input = document.getElementById("map-directions").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("map-txt").value = document.getElementById("map-directions").innerHTML;

    // trigger the update:
    $('#map-txt').trigger('change');

    setTimeout(load, 800);
}
```

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean. putting $('#map-txt').trigger('change'); in my AJAX code won't do anything though!

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you use to update your input field with AJAX.

Comment: Where did you put the `$('#map-txt').trigger('change');`? See my updated answer

Comment: okay, and I did that but as I said, it wont do anything! what is that suppose to do?

Comment: It should trigger your `$('#map-txt').change(function(e){ ..}` function. How are you checking it is not doing anything? Because your function doesn't output anything.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple suggestion :

1 : initialize the value of myVar  so myVar = myData

2 : use a timer to check periodically if the value of myData is changed

code :

```
// store the initial value of $('#mytext') in the initialValue variable

myVar = $('#myText').val();

setInterval(function(){

if(myVar != $('#myText').val()){

console.log('changed ');

// change the content of the initialValue
myVar =  $('#myText').val();

}

},2000);
```

**note** here that **2000** is the time to wait and then check the value of $('#myText').val() if it is changed

hope this is what you want